Spring Batch Partitioned Approach: Multiple batches if triggered together-serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions error
When multiple batches are getting triggered together getting below error,
rg.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: JDBC commit; ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt.
Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:115)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager.translateException(JdbcTransactionManager.java:178)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:340)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:660)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:410)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:207)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy238.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:145)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59)
at com.finastra.retailbanking.essence.febp.service.impl.FebpApplicationJobServiceImpl.triggerApplicationBatchJob(FebpApplicationJobServiceImpl.java:165)
@Service
public class FebpApplicationJobServiceImpl implements FebpApplicationJobService {

  /** The LOGGER. */
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FebpApplicationJobServiceImpl.class);

  /** The app context. */
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext appContext;

  /** The job launcher. */
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("febpBatchJobLauncher")
  private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  /** The job explorer. */
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("febpBatchJobExplorer")
  private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

  /** The job repository. */
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("febpBatchJobRepository")
  private JobRepository jobRepository;

  /** The BatchStatusUpdateThread. */
  private BatchStatusUpdateThread batchStatusUpdateThread;
  /**
   * Trigger or resume application batch job.
   *
   * @param applicationJobDataDTO the application job data DTO
   * @return the response entity
   */
  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<ApplicationJobDataResDTO> triggerOrResumeApplicationBatchJob(ApplicationJobDataReqDTO applicationJobDataDTO) {
    ApplicationJobDataResDTO applicationJobDataResDTO = new ApplicationJobDataResDTO();
    if (applicationJobDataDTO.getAppRestartJobExecutionId() == null || applicationJobDataDTO.getAppRestartJobExecutionId().isEmpty()) {
      BatchStatus appJobStatus = triggerApplicationBatchJob(applicationJobDataDTO, applicationJobDataResDTO);
      applicationJobDataResDTO.setAppJobStatus(appJobStatus != null ? appJobStatus.toString() : null);
    } else {
      BatchStatus appJobResumeStatus = null;
      try {
        appJobResumeStatus = resumeApplicationBatchJob(applicationJobDataDTO.getAppRestartJobExecutionId(), applicationJobDataResDTO);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error during resume FEBP Batch Job:  ", e);
      }
      applicationJobDataResDTO.setAppJobStatus(appJobResumeStatus != null ? appJobResumeStatus.toString() : null);

    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(applicationJobDataResDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  /**
   * Trigger application batch job.
   *
   * @param applicationJobDataDTO    the application job data DTO
   * @param applicationJobDataResDTO
   * @return the batch status
   */
  private BatchStatus triggerApplicationBatchJob(ApplicationJobDataReqDTO applicationJobDataDTO, ApplicationJobDataResDTO applicationJobDataResDTO) {
    JobExecution jobExecution = null;
    try {
      IBatchJobFactory batchJobFactory = (IBatchJobFactory) appContext.getBean(applicationJobDataDTO.getAppJobBeanName());
      Job appJob = batchJobFactory.getBatchJob(ApplicationThreadLocal.getTenantId(), applicationJobDataDTO);
      Map<String, Object> appJobParamsMap = applicationJobDataDTO.getAppJobParamsMap();
      JobParameters appJobParams = configureJobParameters(appJobParamsMap);
      jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(appJob, appJobParams);
      applicationJobDataResDTO.setAppJobExecutionId(String.valueOf(jobExecution.getId()));
      getBatchStatusUpdateThread().addJobToMap(jobExecution.getId(), appJob.getName(), applicationJobDataDTO.getApplicationCode());
      return BatchStatus.STARTED;
    } catch (final JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
      LOGGER.error("JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: ", e);
    } catch (final JobRestartException e) {
      LOGGER.error("JobRestartException: ", e);
    } catch (final JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
      LOGGER.error("JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: ", e);
    } catch (final JobParametersInvalidException e) {
      LOGGER.error("JobParametersInvalidException: ", e);
    } catch (final NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
      LOGGER.error("No Job bean name defined with {}", applicationJobDataDTO.getAppJobBeanName());
      EventMessageSupport.getInstance().raiseBusinessEvent(EventMessageConstant.INVALID_BEAN_NAME, applicationJobDataDTO.getAppJobBeanName());
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Exception: ", e);
    }
    return BatchStatus.FAILED;
  }

  /**
   * Instance of BatchStatusUpdateThread.
   * 
   * @return Instance of batchStatusUpdateThread
   */
  private BatchStatusUpdateThread getBatchStatusUpdateThread() {
    if (batchStatusUpdateThread == null) {
      batchStatusUpdateThread = appContext.getBean(BatchStatusUpdateThread.class);

    }
    return batchStatusUpdateThread;
  } 

And error is at           jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(appJob, appJobParams);
